# What is the blue highlighting in emacs octave mode?

Tags: emacs, octave

When I'm using emacs and octave, sometimes certain lines of code get bolded, and if I put the mouse pointer over them then they get a blue background.

This is slightly disturbing and annoying, and yet I wonder if it might be a really useful thing if only I knew what the hell was going on.

Does anyone know what it's for?

---

I don't think it's anything to do with the particular code, but just in case, the code I was looking at was:

```
nnout=sigmoid(Theta2*([ones(1,m);sigmoid(Theta1*([ones(m,1), X])')])); 
vecy=eye(10)(:,y); 
errs=nnout-eye(10)(:,y); 
-sum(log(1-abs(nnout(:,1)-vecy(:,1))))
```

The first line was normal, but the next three were in bold, and putting the mouse pointer over any one of them highlighted that line in blue. Closing and reopening the buffer put them back to normal.

Comment: Can you give an example of some code that would produce this effect?

Comment: Well, I don't think it's anything to do with the code, but I'm currently looking at four lines. The first:
nnout=sigmoid(Theta2*([ones(1,m);sigmoid(Theta1*([ones(m,1), X])')])); is normal but the next three are in bold, and I get this blue highlight:
vecy=eye(10)(:,y);

errs=nnout-eye(10)(:,y);

-sum(log(1-abs(nnout(:,1)-vecy(:,1)))) --- closing and reopening the buffer puts it back to normal, but I haven't noticed what causes it.

Comment: Code formatting is not preserved in comments. I've taken the liberty of editing your example into the question itself, where it can be formatted properly.

Comment: Well, as you've said, simply putting the code into an octave-mode buffer doesn't trigger the behavior. If you can figure out what action triggers the highlighting, please edit the question with more details. One trick you can use is to open a new frame with `make-frame` and keep the file visible in that second frame. That way if it happens while you are working on something else in your main window, you won't miss it.

Comment: If the mouse-over is what triggers the behavior, then the code is probably being treated by Emacs as a link . . . or a similar concept that is available in octave mode -- so you are looking for mouse-over triggers based upon regexp criteria of what is under the pointer.